# How to color countries using ggmap - r

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I am using the global terrorism data set from Kaggle, and I'm trying to plot on a world map (or just Europe and neighboring countries).
I need to plot the terror attacks as points: size - number killed.
I also need to color the countries according to the number of immigrants in them - that I would require an input from a different data set.
So far what I have got is:

```
df <- read.csv("C:.../globalterrorismdb_0617dist.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

locs <- data.frame(lon = df$longitude, lat = df$latitude, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

nMap <- get_map("Vienna, Austria", zoom = 4, maptype = "toner", source = "stamen")

ggmap(nMap) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = locs$lon, y = locs$lat ,color = df$nkill), data = df) + 
  geom_point(size = 6, alpha = 0.3)
```

which gives me:
[image: Terror attacks locations]

The important part of the attacks data looks like:

```
>    Country,                 latitude,          longitude  
>    United Kingdom           54.59727            -5.930109 
>    Spain                    43.18418            -2.473289 
>    Turkey                   37.95032            27.373266 
>    Italy                    41.89052            12.494249
>    United Kingdom           54.22641            -7.649053
```

Now I would like as mentioned to color countries according to the number of refugees and/or immigrants. For that purpose, lets assume I have a data set which contains that in the form of (fake numbers):

```
>    country,                 # 
>    United Kingdom           123 
>    Spain                    100  
>    Turkey                   250 
>    Italy                    80
```

Please help.

Comment: You want to provide a sample data. Otherwise nobody knows how your data is like; you are unlikely to receive a help from SO users. In addition, your question will become a reference for others in the future. You want to help them so that they can learn from your case. Please revise your question adding your sample data.

Comment: I did that now. Hopefully it is fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach for overlaying country polygons on the base map provided by `ggmap::get_map`:

1. Download the desired background map using `ggmap::get_map`.  Note that the structure returned by this function includes the bounding box as an attribute, which can be accessed as `attr(nMap, "bb")` (where `nMap` is the object returned by `get_map`).  It will be needed later.
2. Get country map data using `ggplot2::map_data("world")` and join any additional variables from the country-level dataset, e.g., using `merge` or `dplyr`'s join functions.
3. Because some countries may be partially in the bounding box, you will need to clip the polygons to the bounding box.  The function `PBSmapping::clipPolys` provides this capability.
4. Use `geom_polygon` to overlay the country polygons on the base map.

Sample code and output follow.

```
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(PBSmapping) # to clip polygons
require(ggthemes) # for theme_map, if desired

# define data (a simple dataset is constructed here
# for illustration purposes) and background map
countryData<-data.frame(region=factor(c("France", "Germany", "Libya")), data=c(2, 15, 1))
nMap <- get_map("Vienna, Austria",zoom=4,maptype="toner",source="stamen")

#get country polygon data
mapdata <- map_data("world")
mapdata <- left_join(mapdata, countryData, by="region")

#get bounding box for map
bb<-attr(nMap, "bb");
ylim<-c(bb$ll.lat, bb$ur.lat)
xlim<-c(bb$ll.lon, bb$ur.lon)

#clip polygons to map
colnames(mapdata)[1:6] <- c("X","Y","PID","POS","region","subregion")
mapdata<-clipPolys(mapdata, xlim=xlim, ylim=ylim, keepExtra=TRUE)

#plot map overlay
ggmap(nMap)+coord_map(xlim=xlim,ylim=ylim) +
    geom_polygon(data=mapdata, aes(x=X, y=Y, group=PID, fill=data), alpha=0.5) +
    ggthemes::theme_map()
```

[image: choropleth output]

Comment: Thank you! And if I would like to add the points now, I just add the geom_point the same as before? (notice that I added an example above)

Comment: I'm asking because it is a different data frame, with a different number of rows. While the country colors is a single row per country, there are multiple points per country. So I'm not sure how to deal with that.

Comment: Yes, you could add the `geom_point` after the `geom_polygon` (in that order so that points show in front of the polygons).  To create a single row per country, you can aggregate the existing dataset by country; with the `dplyr` package, you can use `countryData<-worldmap %>% group_by(region) %>% summarize(data=n()) %>% rename(country=region) ` to create a compatible dataset.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not really proficient enough so I have followup questions.
If I aggregate all point coordinates to a single line, how could I address those? 
If the answers lies in the line of code you wrote here, than I'm not sure what you did there as you were using variables that weren't in your original code: worldmap, region, data=n (which should be n), and why should I use rename?

Again sorry but I'm really new to all that type of work :\

Comment: In my last comment, `worldmap` should have been `df` (your original dataset).  The function `n()` counts the number of rows, and renaming `country` to `region` facilitates merging with the polygon data produced by `map_data` (where the country is in the column `region`.  You may want to look at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html for an overview of dplyr and its functions, as well as documentation the join functions specifically (e.g., `outer_join`).

Comment: Thanks again. I'll try that tonight or tomorrow morning and will updated the post.

Comment: When I'm trying to do the left_join with the worldmap it runs for a long time (waited more than an hour). What could be the problem?

Comment: I'd suggest a new question for that. It's difficult to assess performance without the actual dataset.

Comment: I have everything plotted now, but I cannot manipulate the color, size and opacity of the points. 
ggmap(nMap)+coord_map(xlim=xlim,ylim=ylim) +
  geom_polygon(data=mapdata, aes(x=X, y=Y, group=PID, fill= Acceptance), alpha=0.7) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Reds") + geom_point(aes(x=locs$lon, y=locs$lat, colour = '#F0E442'),data=df) + ggthemes::theme_map()

If I add any color (by name or code) it just set the color to light red. If I add size, it sets to the points to huge ones (doesn't matter what I change). 
Is there some extra line I should add to control the points separatly?

Comment: Adding `color='#F0E442'` in `geom_point` will override the color set by `scale_fill_brewer`.  Generally within `aes`, you will set the aesthetic to a specific column, e.g., `aes(size=count, fill=factor(categoricalColumnName))` (where `count` and `categoricalColumnName` are columns in the dataset).  If you want to set the aesthetic to a specific value, you would do so outside the aesthetic mapping, e.g., `geom_point(color=red, aes(size=count))`.